# Inbox notifications are not always shown

Tags: support, global-inbox

I often find while using Stack Exchange that my alerts in my inbox doesn't show the red box with a number in it in the header. This is annoying if I have my sound turned down, or if I walk away from my computer.

My question is:

Is this a bug? Or is it not supposed to show the notification every time?

Comment: On what browser is this? Can you verify if the [websockets](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/158100) work reliable in your network? If it doesn't work are there specific messages in your inbox?

Answer (score 1):

It should be shown every time you have a new inbox item.  One thing that might be happening is you may have the inbox open in one of your browsers.  Any inbox that is currently open on any browser automatically clears the inbox notification.  Make sure and close all browsers and see if this issue continues.